# Binding control to Object vs DataRow

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I wrote some example code to demonstrate my question. one is bound to Object and other to DataRow:

Bind to DataRow example:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmBindExample : Form
    {
        public frmBindExample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitForm();
        }



        private void InitForm()
        {
            //;; Init the list
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "5476", "Smith" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "5477", "Marlin" });


            Label label1 = new Label() { Top = 130, Left = 10, Text = "Id of Smith is:" };
            this.Controls.Add(label1);

            //;; Bind two direction with TextBox. 
            TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox() { Top = 130, Left = 130, Width = 100 };
            this.Controls.Add(textbox1);
            textbox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt.Rows[0], "Id");


            //;; The binding system respose changing property value
            Button button1 = new Button() { Top = 160, Left = 10, Width = 200, Text = "Set Id=99 Directly by property" };
            this.Controls.Add(button1);
            button1.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                dt.Rows[0]["Id"] = "99";
            };

            DataGridView dg = new DataGridView() { Top = 200, Left = 10 };
            this.Controls.Add(dg);
            dg.DataSource = dt;
        }


    }
}
```

It's look like:

[image]

As you can see, the binding to TextBox not work as it on next example. But, when I update the field by pressing on the button, the data grid refresh immediately:

[image]

Ok, now take look what hempen if I bind Object instead:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmBindExample : Form
    {
        public frmBindExample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitForm();
        }


        private void InitForm()
        {
            //;; Init the list
            List<Person> lst = new List<Person>();
            lst.Add(new Person() { Id = "5476", Name = "Smith" });
            lst.Add(new Person() { Id = "5477", Name = "Marlin" });


            Label label1 = new Label() { Top = 130, Left = 10, Text = "Id of Smith is:" };
            this.Controls.Add(label1);

            //;; Bind two direction with TextBox. 
            TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox() { Top = 130, Left = 130, Width = 100 };
            this.Controls.Add(textbox1);
            textbox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", lst[0], "Id");

            //;; The binding system respose changing property value
            Button button1 = new Button() { Top = 160, Left = 10, Width = 200, Text = "Set Id=99 Directly by property" };
            this.Controls.Add(button1);
            button1.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                lst[0].Id = "99";
            };

            DataGridView dg = new DataGridView() { Top = 200, Left = 10 };
            this.Controls.Add(dg);
            dg.DataSource = lst;
        }

    }


    //;; The person class can bind any his property without any extra call fo change detection 
    public class Person
    {
        public string Id { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, the TextBox show the Id value as we aspect. But push on the Set button not refresh data on the DataGrid.

So, my question is:

1. Why binding TextBox not work correctly on the first example?
2. It's true to say, that automatic (without any extra call for do binding) propagate update from source to control happens only with DataRow?

Comment: Use a `BindingList<Person>` instead of a `List<T>`. Also, use `textbox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", lst, "Id");`

Comment: I try: BindingList<Person> lst = new BindingList<Person>();, but it's not change the results. The DatagridView stil not refresh as happened at DataRow version.

Comment: I don't see the code for that. You can do a couple of things: 1) Add an event handler for `TextBox.TextChanged` event. In the handler method, call `this.dg.UpdateCellValue(0, this.dg.CurrentRow.Index);` 2) Create a `BindingSource` and set its `DataSource` to your List. While adding the Binding to the TextBox, subscribe to the `Parse` event of the Binding, there call `[YourBindingSource].CurrencyManager.Refresh();`. Many more methods available.

Comment: Yes. you right, with extra code I can do it. But I see that have big different between types of DataSource, Datatable and BindingList with object property. The first one refresh the UI without any extra code. I asking if this conclusion is correct, and binding with object property must extra code to get refresh.

Comment: Not with a BindingSource. If you set the `BindingSource.DataSource` to your `BindingList`, then add Bindings to the TextBox properties using the `BindingSource` as DataSource and also use the `BindingSource` as the `DataGridView.DataSource`, the update will be automatic. I suggested to subscribe to the `Parse` event of the Binding because you might want to validate the value entered before submitting the new value. If you need an example, let me know.

Comment: It's work the same. But i'm asking about automatic view refresh when update made on the Person.id side. Then I see the diff between Object to DataRow, When we use Datarow we get automatic view update.

Comment: Test the code shown here, exactly how it is. You'll see that any edit of the `TextBox.Text` is reflected directly and immediately on the bound Property or Column, thus the DataGridView cell is updated instantly and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Since, maybe, describing this procedure in the comments in not a great idea, here's the *enlarged* version.

- Define a [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1) or a `List<T>` as the data storage object (I prefer a `BindingList`, but a simple `List`, here, will do the job anyway).
- Define a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) that will provide change notifications and currency management. It greatly simplifies the binding of controls in WinForms (the class object should implement `INotifyProeprtyChanged`, but for the purpose of this example is not important. It may become important in more specific scenarios, when you have two-way bindings that need to update the UI and the source of data immediately).
- Set the [BindingSource.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource) property to the object that provides the data: here, a **`BindingList`** or an **`IList`**.
- Add a [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding) to the **`TextBox.Text`** property which will be bound to a property of the Data source (or a Column of a DataTable, for example), setting the [`DataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.datasource?view=netframework-4.7.2) value of the `Binding` to the **`BindingSource`** and the **`DataMember`** value to the Property (or Column) of the data source to which the TextBox property is bound. Here, the `Id` property of the **`Input`** class.
- Subscribe to the [Parse event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse) of the TextBox **`Binding`**, to provide means to validate the data entered in the TextBox before allowing an update of the Data source. If the value entered doesn't fit the description (i.e., a user entered letters instead of numbers), we can call, for example, the [BindingSource.ResetCurrentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetcurrentitem) method to cancel the data update
- Set the **`DataGridView.DataSource`** to the `BindingSource`.

This is what happens, using the code shown here:

[image: DataBindings BindingSource]

---

**Note**:
I'm using a lambda here to subscribe to the **`Parse`** event; you may want to use a separate handler if you need to subscribe/unsubcribe to this event more than once.

```
internal class Input
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal List<Input> inputData = new List<Input>();
internal BindingSource bindingSource;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource = new BindingSource();

    inputData.AddRange(new [] { 
        new Input() { Id = 5476, Name = "Smith" },
        new Input() { Id = 5477, Name = "Marlin" }
    });

    bindingSource.DataSource = inputData;

    Binding tboxBind = new Binding("Text", bindingSource, "Id", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

    tboxBind.Parse += (pObj, pEvt) =>
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(pEvt.Value.ToString(), out int value))
            bindingSource.ResetCurrentItem();
    };
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add(tboxBind);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I asking about change value of data property. Like: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){InputData[0].Id = 99;}. On DtatRow it's refresh immediately, but not on List.

Comment: Yes, it's refreshed immediately. Test the code I've posted, it's self-contained (creates a data container). To try it, add a DataGridView on a Form. You can insert the code in a `Button.Click`, to create the data and the bindings, or in `Form.Load`. See the result, the same as in the animations you see here. Btw, with the DataGridView, the current item is updated when you `EndEdit` the cell, thus when you press `Enter` or `Tab` or otherwise exit the cell.

Answer (score 1):

**Why binding TextBox not work correctly on the first example?**

It's because the `TypeDescriptor` of the `DataRow` doesn't have a `Id` property. Consider the following rules:

- When data binding to a property of an item, the type descriptor of the item should contain a property with that name.
- When data binding to a list, the list item type descriptor should contain a property with that name.

**Is it true to say, that automatic (without any extra call for do binding) propagate update from source to control happens only with DataRow?**

No. It's not because of `DataRow` type. It's because of `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IBindingList`. Consider the following rules:

- When data binding a control to an item, if the item implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then UI will be updated immediately after updating item.
- When data-binding to a list control, if the item Implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the list implement `IBindingList`, the UI will be updated immediately after updating item or list.

**More information**

What I described above in short, you can find in details in [Windows Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding). I recommend reading the following useful documents:

- [Data Sources Supported by Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/data-sources-supported-by-windows-forms)
- [Interfaces Related to Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/interfaces-related-to-data-binding)
- [Change Notification in Windows Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/change-notification-in-windows-forms-data-binding)

Comment: The post is directly answering your questions. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.